# how to auto-increment with 1 and append decimal if row value like 1st row else 2

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

i have this code to generate a report joining two table.

```
$agebracket= $_POST['age_bracket'];   //coming from dropdown list

$sql=mysql_query("select qshortcode from question_details  where pans1 like '%$agebracket%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 $utility[] = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','',$row['qshortcode']);              
}
$slno=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($utility);$i++) {
$last=""; //as suggested
$check=mysql_query("select q.qshortcode,q.qcode,q.question,p.paid_rev from question_details q left outer join paid_response p on q.qcode=p.qno where q.qshortcode like '$utility[$i]%' group by q.qcode");
    while($qscode=mysql_fetch_array($check)) {  

      if($last =substr($qscode['qcode'],strlen($last))) { 
       $last = $qscode['qcode'];          
       $slno++;
       $slid = $slno ;
      } else {
        $slid .= ".1";
      }

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$slid.' '."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$qscode['qshortcode'].' '."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$qscode['qcode'].' '."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$qscode['question'].' '."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$qscode['paid_rev']."<br></td>";
      echo "</tr>";       
    }       
}
echo "</table>";
```

this generates this report fetching from two  tables with `left outer join` to also get the blank `revenue`

```
SL-No   Qcode     Question    Revenue
  1      test     whatever    
  1.1    test_1   zzz         
  2      test_2   xxx         something    //here it is becoming 2 but it should be 1.1.1
  3      abc      vvv         
  3.1    abc1     khkhk       something
```

now actually i want to auto-increment `SL-No` with 1 then if `qcode` matches like the 1st row `qcode` it will be 1.1 then 1.1.1  then when it dont matches it will be 2. like the report will be like

```
SL-No      Qcode      Question    Revenue
  1         test      whatever    
 1.1       test_1      zzz         
 1.1.1     test_2      xxx         something
  2         abc        vvv         
 2.1       abc1        khkhk       something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this (untested code):

```
$slno=0;
[...] // for loop omitted, just starting at 0 instead of 1, to increment properly after.
$last="-1"; // To avoid comparing two empty lines at first pass, which will obvisouly be alway true, sorry.
while ([mysql query ....]) {
  if ($last != substr($qscode['qcode'],0, strlen($last))) {
    $last = $qscode['qcode'];
    $slno++;
    $slid = strval($slno)
  } else {
   $slid .= ".1"
  }

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$slid.' '."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$qscode['qshortcode'].' '."</td>";
  [...] // rest omitted
}
```

Comment: left($qscode['qcode'],
Fatal error: Call to undefined function left()

Comment: i used substr instead of left() but not incrementing with 0.1 if condition matches but only incrementing with 1

Comment: @black could add your updated code in your question ?

Comment: Yes i used substr($qscode['qcode'],strlen($last)))  instead of left(). it works with only one child. appending 1.1 but not the next child with 1.1.1 instead it gives 2

Comment: @black you didn't read the doc for substr, did you ? Substr(string, start, length)

Comment: your eidted answer ($last != substr($qscode['qcode'],0, strlen($last))) outputs to 1.   .1.1   .1.1.1   .1.1.1.1  but with ($last = substr($qscode['qcode'], strlen($last)))  gives almost what is expected plz see my edited question with result i am getting right now and what is expected

Comment: everything is working fine with this code but not just what i wanted. as the same next row is giving 1.1  but not if again another found it should be 1.1.1  but instead throwing 2

Comment: With a single = you're assigning the value... And reassigning it just after (as the assignment return 1). Updating again to cast to string (but unsure)

Comment: no man same thing is coming .1 then .1.1  then .1.1.1   then .1.1...n  the number of rows returned

Comment: Try initializing $last with something like -1 (something not in your qcode possibility if possible)

Comment: @black updated answer for the reason, sorry to have forgotten this :/